# Can we pass two args in url - django?

Tags: html, django, parameters, django-templates, django-urls

This is my models.py file for Category and Product

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
    
# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
        objects = models.Manager()
        name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
        slug = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
        desc = models.TextField(blank=True)
    
        class Meta:
            verbose_name = 'category'
            verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
class Product(models.Model):
        objects = models.Manager()
        name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
        slug = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
        desc = models.TextField(blank=True)
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
        class Meta:
            verbose_name = 'product'
            verbose_name_plural = 'products'
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

This is the url file where I am stuck:

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from website import views
urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.home, name='home'),
        path('categorys/<slug:category_slug>/', views.category_product, name='category_product'),
        path('category/<slug:category_slug>/<slug:product_slug>', views.product, name='product_slug'),
]
```

Is it possible to pass two arguments in url, from the html, so that we can pass that to the product function?

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from website.models import Product, Category
    
def home(request):
        allcategories = Category.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'website/home.html', {'allcategories':allcategories})
    
    
def product(request, category_slug, product_slug):
        product = Product.objects.get(category__slug=category_slug, slug=product_slug)
        return render(request, 'website/display_product.html', {'product':product})
    
def category_product(request, category_slug):
        current_category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        product = Product.objects.filter(category=current_category)
        return render(request, 'website/category_product.html',{'current_category':current_category, 'product':product})
```

This is the html page from where i am trying to pass the two args to the urls.py but stuck with errors please guide me , any help is really appreciated , thank you !

**category_product.html**

```
    Category name : {{ current_category.name }} <br>   

    <h3>Products </h3>
    
    {% for p in product %}
        <a href="{% url 'product_slug' arg1=current_category.name arg2=p.slug %}">
            <b>{{ p.name  }}</b>  <br>
        </a>
    {% endfor %}
    
    ## how to pass two args (or is it possible here) so that it will be passed to the urls.py
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: that error is solved but now faced with another one sir ! stackoverflow is not allowing me to put one more question right now or else i have uploaded the code for current one but thanks alot sir and lots of love to you

Answer (score 1):

You have passed as `category_slug` and `product_slug`. But you used as arg1 and arg2 the argument name is important.

**category_product.html**

```
Category name : {{ current_category.name }} <br>   
    
<h3>Products </h3>
        
{% for p in product %}
      <a href="{% url 'product_slug' category_slug=current_category.name product_slug=p.slug %}">
          <b>{{ p.name  }}</b>  <br>
       </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You also welcome :) . Don't forgot to accept this one.